# Husky with lint-staged is keep on running forever for the failure cases

Tags: git, nest, husky, lint-staged

In my project, here is the project structure:

```
client/
.git/
       services/
            nest-services/
               package.json
               apps/
                   app1/
                     ..
                   appn/
// no package.json here under
```

Inside the `nest-services` I want to add the pre-submit lint check (eslint in Nest TypeScript code of app1 only -- to start with).

By looking into various places, I picked up the `Husky` with 'lint-staged`. I installed both husky and lint-staged latest versions.

I setup the husky as follows in the `nest-services/package.json`:

```
    "prepare": "cd ../../ && husky install services/nest-services/.husky"
```

Here is my integration in `nest-services/package.json`:

```
  "lint:app1": "eslint apps/app1/src --format table",
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "apps/app1/src/**/*.ts": [
      "eslint apps/app1/src --format table"
    ]
  }
```

And my `services/nest-services/.husky/pre-submit`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

cd services/nest-services
yarn lint:app1
```

However whenever I am running this in modified staged files, the positive case is working fine. But in case there is a lint failure, it's not stopping. The `lint-stage` is keep on running.

[image]

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Understood the issue.

Please refer to the [lintstaged help](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged).

By default it fires up tasks in parallel. Somehow the `eslint --format table` was not working nicely through `lintstaged` scheduling. So I change

> "lint:app1": "eslint apps/app1/src --format table",

by

> "lint:app1": "yarn lint-staged --quiet --concurrent false --config ./.lintstagedrc"

So overall my `package.json` looks like:

```json
    "lint:prepare": "cd ../../ && husky install services/nest-services/.husky"
    "lint:app1": "yarn lint-staged --quiet --concurrent false --config ./.lintstagedrc"
```

Simple!

And my `lintstagedrc` looks like:

```json
{
  "apps/app1/(src|test)/**/*.(ts|tsx)": [
    "eslint --format table"
  ]
}
```

And my updated `.husky/pre-commit` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

yarn --cwd services/nest-services lint:app1
```

That's all.